# JIT simple optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, jit

I have the following method

```
void DoSome(){
    if (int.Parse(SomeStringProperty) > 8)
        // do something

    if (int.Parse(SomeStringProperty) < 10)
        // do something
}
```

Does the JIT know to keep the parsed value or is it better to do the following:

```
void DoSome(){
    var x = int.Parse(SomeStringProperty);
    if (x > 8)
        // do something

    if (x < 10)
        // do something
}
```

There is two optimizes the I can see here:

1. The JIT automatically will do something like the second example
2. The JIT do the one optimization and cache the result

My question its just about the one optimization that will need to be consistent and not about the 2 optimization that can be depending in a lot of factors.

In short, when I write C# app what of the above examples is preferred?

**Update**

If the answer is not, why its different from this:

```
foreach (var x in MyMethod.GetEnumeration())
```

here there no need to do:

```
var lst = MyMethod.GetEnumeration();
foreach (var x in lst)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't. In general it doesn't optimize out calls to complex functions. `int.Parse` isn't even pure in the strictest sense, since it access global mutable state related to the current culture.

Comment: In second case you need `var x = int.Parse(SomeStringProperty);`. Fix and use this option - you never can be sure with JIT (it depends on platform and Moon phase)

Comment: I usually prefer the second approach because it don't call a function and it's anyway a String parse (String = Slow in almost every case (especially if long)). I'm not sure if JIT optimizate it but i don't think (how can it manage multi-threading? save last change? bit to check?).

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i'm agree about the Moon phase of the JIT but i thought the first optimization need to be consistent. anyway probably i'll use the second option

Comment: @MarcoLopezAcierno this hlaf true becouse the JIT do optimization also in multithreaded case. see here please: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the general case, no. Because: side-effects. In general, `any.Method(args)` can do something different **every time** (logging, randomness, incrementing counters, connecting to an external unmanaged resource, etc), and must be called each time to retain the original semantic. It *could be* that a white-list of "pure" functions is maintained, but I can think of no special reason to include `int.Parse` in that.

Basically, if you want to hoist it: hoist it yourself. The code in your second example is reasonable (personally I'd add an `else`, i.e `else if`).

---

Additionally: your example calls `SomeStringProperty` multiple times : ***that too*** must be called multiple times to retain the semantic, and could behave differently.

Finally, in a multi-threaded world, the field itself ***could have changed***.

Comment: And a simple test with a for cycle reveals that at the moment, on my .NET JIT, the code is not optimized even if you use a string literal. Now, int.Parse isn't exactly slow, but it's much much much slower than the comparison. Especially if the value of x gets stored in a register, rather than in RAM.

Comment: @Marc thanks for the answer. please take a look at my update q.

Comment: @Marc my example is not so good... its not a real method and i understand what you mean but I ask on a general case. lets say the SomePropertyString will not change and even if it will change i dont care. and lets say there is no if statement but just two calss to int.Parse()

Comment: @Marc "Finally, in a multi-threaded world, the field itself could have changed". yes but see here that the JIT optimize even in a multithreaded world: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Comment: @Maya indeed; but that only applies to field access; you are calling multiple methods - they must still be called; now they could be *inlined*, but: then it would be inlined *in both places*

Answer (score 1):

Re the update: that example is completely unrelated. You might as well give an example of:

```
var val = MyMethod.SomeMethod();
```

and compare it to:

```
var tmp = MyMethod.SomeMethod();
var val = tmp;
```

in both cases, all you've done is separate the invoke/evaluation from the usage by way of assignment into an intermediary variable. And, in both cases, if we assume that the `lst` / `tmp` variable isn't used anywhere else, we can be reasonably sure that the compiler (not the JIT) actually removes that variable anyway - so the two are not just *logically* equivalent - they are *actually* equivalent. In this scenario, we haven't removed any method calls etc - we only evaluate it once. Completely unrelated scenario.

Comment: thanks again. and yes sure its compile time optimization. BTW in the foreach example, if i use temp var that i use it later in the method and in the foreach i call to method explicit do i understand correct that no optimization will occur?. hope i was understood...